# Deeplearning4j: System Freezes During Multi-threaded Inference despite Separate Model Instances

Tags: java, multithreading, deeplearning4j, nd4j

I'm encountering performance issues when running Deeplearning4j in a multi-threaded environment. My system slows down or gets stuck while trying inferences (fit instead works, i do fit on the main model and output on the copied models), despite creating separate model instances for each thread.

**Expected Behavior:**
I expect the model to perform inference efficiently in a multi-threaded context.

**Actual Behavior:**
After several inference operations, the system dramatically slows down or gets stuck.

**Setup:**
I'm using Deeplearning4j version M2 on a Mac system with an i5 3.3GHz processor and 16 GB RAM. ND4J version is M2.1

**Current Approach:**
I create a new `ComputationGraph` instance for each thread before performing inference. Here's a snippet of my code for cloning the model:

```java
// Existing model
ComputationGraph model = ...;

// Cloning for each thread
ComputationGraph clone = model.clone();

// Example inference code in each thread
INDArray input = ...; // your input data
INDArray output = clone.output(input);
```

current model:

```java
Map<Integer, Double> learningRateSchedule = new HashMap<>();
                learningRateSchedule.put(0, 2e-5);
                learningRateSchedule.put(833, 2e-6);
                learningRateSchedule.put(1666, 2e-7);
                ISchedule schedule = new MapSchedule(ScheduleType.ITERATION, learningRateSchedule);
ComputationGraphConfiguration.GraphBuilder graphBuilder = new NeuralNetConfiguration.Builder()
                        .seed(System.currentTimeMillis())
                        .weightInit(WeightInit.RELU)
                        .l2(1e-4)
                        .updater(new Adam(schedule))
                        .graphBuilder()
                        .addInputs("input")
                        .setInputTypes(InputType.convolutional(M+2, N, 1));

                String lastLayer = "input";
                for (int i = 0; i < nndepth; i++) {
                    graphBuilder.addLayer("torso_" + i + "_conv", new ConvolutionLayer.Builder()
                            .kernelSize(3,3)
                            .stride(1,1)
                            .nIn(i == 0 ? 1 : numHiddenNodes)
                            .nOut(numHiddenNodes)
                            .padding((3-1)/2, (3-1)/2)//padding per un kernel di 3x3
                            .activation(Activation.RELU)
                            .build(), lastLayer);
                    lastLayer = "torso_" + i + "_conv";
                }
                graphBuilder.addLayer("policy_conv",
                        new ConvolutionLayer.Builder()
                                .nIn(numHiddenNodes)
                                .nOut(numHiddenNodes)
                                .kernelSize(3,3)
                                .padding((3-1)/2, (3-1)/2)//padding per un kernel di 3x3
                                .stride(1,1)
                                .activation(Activation.RELU)
                                .build(),
                        lastLayer);
                graphBuilder.addLayer("policy_output",
                        new OutputLayer.Builder(LossFunctions.LossFunction.NEGATIVELOGLIKELIHOOD)
                                .nIn(numHiddenNodes)
                                .nOut(numOutputs)
                                .activation(Activation.SOFTMAX)
                                .build(),
                        "policy_conv");

                graphBuilder.addLayer("value_conv",
                        new ConvolutionLayer.Builder()
                                .nIn(numHiddenNodes)
                                .nOut(numHiddenNodes)
                                .kernelSize(3,3)
                                .padding((3-1)/2, (3-1)/2)//padding per un kernel di 3x3
                                .stride(1,1)
                                .activation(Activation.RELU)
                                .build(),
                        lastLayer);
                graphBuilder.addLayer("value_output",
                        new OutputLayer.Builder(LossFunctions.LossFunction.MSE)
                                .nIn(numHiddenNodes)
                                .nOut(1)
                                .activation(Activation.IDENTITY)
                                .build(),
                        "value_conv");

                graphBuilder.setOutputs("policy_output", "value_output");

                ComputationGraphConfiguration conf = graphBuilder.build();
                model = new ComputationGraph(conf);
```

i have also tried to experiment with different VM option, last ones i tried are:
-Dlog4j.debug=true
-Dlog4j.configuration=file:"path/log4j.properties"
-Xms16G
-Xmx16g
I monitored CPU and memory usage, but the problem persists.

- Are there specific Deeplearning4j or ND4J configurations that can help in this multi-threaded setup?
- Could there be any underlying issues with my model configuration leading to these performance bottlenecks?
- Any JVM settings or system-level adjustments recommended for such Deeplearning4j workloads?

Any suggestions on how to improve performance or resolve the freezing issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

**UPDATE**
the problem doesn't happen if i remove padding or if i remove multithreading, that means that if only one of these (or both obv) is satisfied it runs

Comment: Any reason you're not using ParallelWrapper/Inference? That's what we wrote it for.

Comment: yes, i searched for it on the deeplearning4j site, I clicked the link and it leaded me to a 404 github page, if u could provide me the reference for it i would be grateful, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use ParallelInference. We will do this for you.

Example usage:

```
ParallelInference inf =
                    new ParallelInference.Builder(model).inferenceMode(InferenceMode.SEQUENTIAL).workers(2).build();
```

Pass in your model and specify the type of inference you want to do and the number of workers. Note this will replicate the copy of the model to each thread.

Comment: sorry is it possible to use it with multiple outputs and computationgraph?

Comment: Yes it works with both.